# React Native - Can't understand the purpose of FlatList extraData prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I understand that the FlatList extraData prop is used to re-render components when it changes.

So, imagine this example:

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text, FlatList } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [selectedId, setSelectedId] = React.useState(null);

  const items = [
    {
      id: 'some-unique-id',
      title: 'Item 1',
    },
  ];

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <SelectableItem
        selected={selectedId === item.id}
        onPress={() => setSelectedId(item.id)}
      />
    );
  };

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={items}
      renderItem={renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      extraData={selectedId} // works the same if I remove this
    />
  );
}

function SelectableItem({ selected, onPress }) {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={{ backgroundColor: selected ? 'red' : 'white' }}
      onPress={onPress}>
      <Text>Click Me!</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```

I have implemented it thinking in re-render the component when the FlatList state changes...

Test it [here](https://snack.expo.dev/hbKgvvbUD).

But, the code works the same if I remove the extra data prop... why?

Answer (score 0):

As the document suggests

> By passing extraData to FlatList we make sure FlatList will re-render itself when the state. selected changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.

I think it is because your state is changing the components are updated but in all cases, it's not possible like if you want to change the array and it doesn't affect the state the component will not be updated and the flat list will be the same. We are using an extra data prop to notify the flat list that data has been changed and it should re render.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I still don't understand. So, if for example, data (stateful) is changed (an item has been removed from it), the flatlist will not be re-rendered?

Comment: https://snack.expo.dev/wFgOwVWTN

Answer (score 0):

I am confused by the official demo too. You can find it here :[selectable example](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist?language=typescript). As the value of [renderItem prop] and [keyExtractor prop] will change when App is re-render, [extraData] in this demo is not necessary at all.

Though we can use [useCallback] hook to cache these two function definitions, renderItem function still needs to access selectedId state, which needs we use selectedId like this: `useCallback(renderItemFunction,[selectedId])`. But Using selectedId in this way will make cached reference of renderItem function changed when selectedId is updated, which makes [extraData] unnecessary again.

You can check out this article for a better understanding: [2022-dont-rerender-all-flatlist-items](https://brainsandbeards.com/blog/2022-dont-rerender-all-flatlist-items/)

Anyway, I think they should update the logic of this official demo. The purpose and logic are too weird.